# LEFT JOIN ON string match Very slow

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to perform this LEFT JOIN but it's very slow (30.000ms) because of the match on text string.
How can I make it faster?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b ON (
    table_b.state    = 'enabled'         AND
    table_b.group_id =  5  AND 
    ( 
    (                      
        LOWER(table_b.text) = LOWER(table_a.query)
    ) 
        OR
    (
        table_b.match_type = 'phrase' AND 
        table_a.query ILIKE '%'  || table_b.text || '%'
    )   
    )
)
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to break this into two queries, one that does a left join with `LOWER(table_b.text) = LOWER(table_a.query)`, supported by index `on table_b (lower(text),group_id,state)`.  And one that does a inner join with `table_b.match_type = 'phrase' AND table_a.query ILIKE '%'  || table_b.text || '%'`, supported by an index `on table_a using gin (query gin_trgm_ops)`.  And then have the results from the 2nd query overwrite the results from the first one for the relevant rows.

This could be implemented either on the client side, or by combining the queries with UNION ALL and then wrapping that in a DISTINCT ON to keep the correct rows.  With the info you provided, we can't tell you how to implement the "correct rows".  Does table_a have a primary or unique key?

Comment: Why not implementing this index on table A too?
table_a (lower(query))

Comment: Due to the left join, it is hard to see how that index would help much.  Perhaps you could do a Left Merge Join where that index provides the ordering, in which case pair it with an index `on table_b (group_id,state,lower(text))`.  But those are rarely superior to (Left/Right) Hash Join, unless you are memory constrained from using the Hash.